# submitting a form automatically using javascript stuck in a continuous loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just wondering where i am going wrong with this code it adds the £95 to the checkout but the problem is it repeatedly does it like its in a loop and i cant seem to figure how to stop it.

```
<body onLoad="submit1()">
<form method="post" action="" class="jcart" id="foo">
 <fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['jcartToken'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="ABC-8" />
<input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="Level 1" />
<input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="95.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="" />

<table>
      <tr>
      <td width="65%">
    <strong>Level 1 all for £95</strong>
      </td>

      <td width="15%" align="right">
    £95.00
      </td>

  <td>
        <input type="text" hidden ="true" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" hidden="true" />
  </td>
      <td width="20%" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" id="my-add-button" value="add" class="button" /> 
  </td>
  </tr>
     </table>       
</fieldset>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submit1() {    
    // It seems that its this causing the problem 
    document.getElementById("my-add-button").click()// Simulates button click

    document.foo.submit() // Submits the form without the button
} 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have got it to work kinda but only if you hit F5 to refresh the page     `$(document).ready(function(){

            //Check if the current URL contains '#' 
            if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1)
            {
    url = document.URL+"#";
       location = "#";   
    
            } else {
    location.reload(true);
       document.getElementById("my-add-button").click();// Simulates button click
     document.foo.submit(); // Submits the form without the button 
   }
   
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call submit1() in body onload it gets executed everytime page is being loaded. Since this function submits form which loads the page again it creates a loop. Delete submit1() function and try this simpler approach:

```
$("#my-add-button").click(function() {
    $("#foo").submit();
});
```

Comment: Nothing seems to happen looking at the jcart.js it uses this to add to the cart `$('.jcart').submit(function(e) {    add($(this));    e.preventDefault();   });` if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var o = 0;
function submit1() {
    if(o === 0){
      document.foo.submit() // Submits the form without the button
    }
    (o === 0) ? o++ : o = 0;
}
```

Comment: same as above nothing seems to happen looking at the jcart.js it uses this to add to the cart `$('.jcart').submit(function(e) {    add($(this));    e.preventDefault();   });` if that helps